# Inconsistent formatting on company page's "industry" and "seniority" icons

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs, tooltips

In the jobs, for any company page there are two icons visible above the **Job Description** section.

When hovering on the icons I see the titles like **Seniority** and **(Industries)**.

1. These titles are visible only in Firefox, not on Chrome and Internet Explorer.
2. Why parenthesis added for the **(Industries)**

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Stack Overflow Jobs tool tip]

- Firefox: 50.0
- Chrome: 51.0.2704.103 m
- Internet Explorer: 11.0.9600.18205
- OS: Windows 8

Comment: Can you share your HTML code please

Comment: @Nimmi: In this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/100811/application-developer-bangalore-chennai-sahaj-software-solutions-pvt), you can inspect the element for the icons to get the HTML code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done, I've fixed these and while I was in there I deleted the `aria-hidden` attribute for the icons that provide context for browser readers.

Comment: The issue is fixed. Same kind of fix needed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338514/2451726)