# Company page icon tool tip is visible in Firefox only

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs, tooltips

In the jobs, for any [company page's About us](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/100811/application-developer-bangalore-chennai-sahaj-software-solutions-pvt) section (usually in the right hand side bar), there are three visible icons.

In Firefox I can see the tooltip for two icons (Status and Founded), but in Chrome and Internet Explorer the tooltips are not visible.

[Same kind of fix](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338467/2451726) need to apply here too.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Title visible only in Firefox]

- Firefox: 50.0
- Chrome: 51.0.2704.103 m
- Internet Explorer: 11.0.9600.18205
- OS: Windows 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done, same tweaks to the `aria-hidden` attribute (it will be deployed on the next build)

Comment: Issue fixed in the `rev 2016.12.8.4306`